# How can I move the position of a cue for the second shot in a pool game

Tags: game-engine

I am trying to build a pool game but having difficulty with the position of the cue after the break shot. I can get the cue to move in a number of ways but none of them face the cue in the right direction. Please can anyone suggest a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:
[image]

A very simple rig: The bone that controls the cue is parented to another bone that represents the cue's target. You can move and rotate the parent bone to match the position of the target, and rotate it to the angle you want to strike from; the cue will revolve around the target accordingly. Then you can control the movement of the cue toward the target by moving its bone along the local Y axis.

[image]